# JQGRID in spring mvc and hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

How to show data from oracle 10g table in a jqGrid using spring and hibernate?
There are some data present in the table and I want to show them in a editable jqGrid table in jsp. can anyone guide me how to do it.

```
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
                throws Exception {
    rel_details reldetails = (rel_details) command;
    List l=reldetailsdao.save_release_details(reldetails);

    JSONObject responseDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    Iterator itr=l.iterator();
    rel_details asd=null;
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        asd=(rel_details)itr.next();

        JSONObject formDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
        formDetailsJson.put("rel_id", asd.getRel_id());
        formDetailsJson.put("rel_name", asd.getRel_name());
        formDetailsJson.put("rel_modified_date", asd.getRel_modified_date());
        formDetailsJson.put("rel_desc", asd.getRel_desc());
        formDetailsJson.put("rel_env", asd.getRel_env());
        formDetailsJson.put("rel_change_req_no", asd.getRel_change_req_no());
        formDetailsJson.put("rel_status", asd.getRel_status());
        jsonArray.add(formDetailsJson);
    }

    responseDetailsJson.put("l", jsonArray);
    System.out.println(responseDetailsJson);

    return new ModelAndView("add_release","rel",responseDetailsJson);
```

Comment: Inside the controller i am able to fetch the data and store as a json . and from [link](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) i downloaded the code for jqgrid . but i dont know how to put that data in that grid

Comment: You need to post the relevant code here

Comment: i posted above the controller

Comment: The controller looks fine what's the problem that you  are facing?

Comment: The problem is that the json which I am passing from the controller  `responseDetailsJson` am unable to put inside a jqgrid or editable datagrid using jquery

Comment: What exactly I mean is the problem? How's you JSON array ?

Comment: the data i am getting from the table . I need to show that in a tabular format which is editable table . you can check here [link](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/treegridjs/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to go through the below steps to show your result in jqgrid if your technology stack is Java and Spring.

1. Create a class *ResponseDTO* that will contain the results and other values that you want to show in jqgrid.
2. Modify the above *onSubmit* method to return the response DTO you created just now in step 1. There is no need to use *JSONObject* or *JSONArray* class.
3. Map the *onSubmit* method to a url and ensure that this method is part of a controller in MVC.
4. Then create a JSP which will refer the above url as below to show and edit the results.

   ```
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#list").jqGrid({
                   datatype: 'json',
                   mtype: 'GET',
                   height: 'auto',
                   url:'actual url that retrieves results i.e., url created in step 3',
                   editurl:'actual url through which you want to edit the data',
                   colNames:['Col Name1','Col Name2','Col Name3'],
                   colModel:[]
                   ..................
                   ..................
             })
          })
   ```
5. You have to have Jackson jar (e.g., jackson-all-x.x.x.jar) in classpath to do the necessary JSON conversion. Accordingly you have to use *@RequestBody* and *@ResponseBody* annotations.

Hope this helps you move forward. In case you have any issue, you can refer the [link](https://programnplay.blogspot.com/2013/07/jqgrid-using-spring-mvc.html) here.